# How to prevent type checking of script files in vite + SSR

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, vite, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to render my vite+react+typescript app on server side.

The following is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["jest", "vite/client"],
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

my tsconfig.node.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

And my vite.config.ts file

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import viteTsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
// import macrosPlugin from 'vite-plugin-babel-macros'
import svgrPlugin from "vite-plugin-svgr";
// import path from 'path'
import { splitVendorChunkPlugin } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
// How to migrate from CRA to vite: https://cathalmacdonnacha.com/migrating-from-create-react-app-cra-to-vite

import dns from "dns";

dns.setDefaultResultOrder("verbatim");

export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    "process.env": {},
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: "stream",
        replacement: `stream-browserify`,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    viteTsconfigPaths(),
    svgrPlugin(),
    splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
  ],
  build: {
    outDir: "build",
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
  ssr: {
    noExternal: ["styled-components", "@emotion/*"],
  },
  server: {
    open: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
  preview: {
    port: 8000,
  },
});
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ssr",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server",
    "build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
    "build:client": "vite build --ssrManifest --outDir dist/client",
    "build:server": "vite build --ssr src/entry-server.tsx --outDir dist/server",
    "preview": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server",
    "test": "jest test",
    "coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "eject": "vite eject",
    "lint": "eslint --fix src && prettier --write \"src/**/*.{html,css,scss,js,ts,tsx}\""
  },
  ........................ REST OF package.json............
```

I have a scripts folder inside my src folder, which contains script files related to a third party library. I am running `npm run dev` to start my node server. I get this error when i start my node server

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ImageAlign')
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\SSR\ssr\src\scripts\umd\diagramming.js:5048:30
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\SSR\ssr\src\scripts\umd\diagramming.js:4037:7
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\SSR\ssr\src\scripts\umd\diagramming.js:4046:3
    at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/SSR/ssr/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-9A4-l-43.js:50861:15)
```

What can i do this fix this error. I tried adding `exclude` with the script folder path to my tsconfig.json, but i did not seem to do anything. Also i have added `// @ts-nocheck` to top of my `diagramming.js` , but i still got the error.

Comment: That's not a typescript error, the javascript is trying to access a variable that is `undefined` `someVar.ImageAlign`. Find the variable in `diagramming.js:5048:30` and figure out why it isn't defined. Likely something to do with expecting a browser environment but running in SSR.

Comment: @Matt my diagramming.js is a minified js file.

Comment: That will make tracing the variable harder.